# RPI.GPIO: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi.GPIO

Tags: python-3.x, gpio, bullseye

Thank you to all the contributors with their posts correlating to `**RPI.GPIO**`. I have tried most of your suggestions but so far to no avail.

My current `version:` 0.7.1a4`, I'm running bullseye on Pi4 and a python3 programm which should **`import the RPi.GPIO as GPIO**`. Instead I get:`  **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi.GPIO'; 'RPi' is not a package**`.

On a bullseye headless the same program imports `**RPi.GPIO as GPIO**` without a problem.

I have tried various `RPi.GPIO` installation methods and am receiving as many different messages in return. But nothing so far has solved anything. And now I am without a clue as to where to look or do next.

**Method 1:**

```
sudo pip3 install numpy --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

**message returned:**

> Requirement already satisfied: ...dist-packages (1.19.5)

**Method 2:**

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

**message returned:**

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not `writeable`
> Requirement already satisfied

**Method 3:**

```
pip3 install RPi.GPIO
```

**message returned:**

> Requirement already satisfied: ...dist-packages `(0.7.1a4)`

**Method 4:**

```
export CFLAGS=-fcommon
pip3 install RPi.GPIO
```

**message returned:**

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not `writeable`
> Requirement already satisfied: ...dist-packages `(0.7.1a4)`

**Method 5:**

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio
```

**message returned:**

> ...already the newest version `(0.7.0-0.2+b1)`.

**Method 6:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
```

**message returned:**

> `python3.rpi.gpio` is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source

**Method 7:**

```
sudo apt-get install RPi.GPIO
```

**message returned:**

> Note, selecting '`python3-rpi.gpio`' for regex '`RPi.GPIO`'
> Note, selecting '`python-rpi.gpio`' for regex '`RPi.GPIO`'
> Note, selecting '`rpi.gpio-common`' for regex '`RPi.GPIO`'
> `python3-rpi.gpio` is already the newest version `(0.7.0-0.2+b1)`.
> `rpi.gpio-common` is already the newest version `(0.7.0-0.2+b1)`.

Thank you for your suggestions & help

Comment: So, why not ask maintainers from distribution to update the package? But better is to switch to `libgpiod` which is a native library for communicating with GPIOs in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I was with the same error, try all the commands and nothing but now I succeed, I hope it helps you, I just put python3 when reading the code from the console, for example: 'sudo python3 testgpio.py' instead of just python, I hope it serves you

Comment: could you please add some more detail as to why your solution worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Turns out I had the wrong operating system. I had the 64 bit Bullseye version to mine monero for a short time. But with the normal Bullseye 11 version everything works just fine. You can download it on the raspberry imager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Replace `RPI.GPIO` with `RPi.GPIO`, the letter *i* in lowercase, because python is case sensitive